# Should one wait with resubmitting revisions until the very last day?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission

A colleague of mine recently suggested to wait with the re-submission of a revised article until the very end (e.g. the deadline day). His rationale is that reviewers might be less inclined to dig in the matter again after a certain time has passed. Based on his experience, the chances of acceptance are therefore higher.
I doubt this believing that the revised version content is the only decisive factor.
May I ask whether you agree on said colleague's statement?

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, both as author and reviewer, and looking also at my closest's colleague behaviour, your colleague's statement is unfounded.

I'd say that the willingness by the reviewers to dig in the matter again  depends mostly on the types of issues found at the time of the first submission, on the interest generated by the paper and on the journal's perceived quality.

Personally, I tend to resubmit as soon as I can find the time to do it, possibly within a few days, for two reasons. First, tasks always pile up and there's always the possibility that incoming urgencies make it difficult to complete certain tasks or easy to forget about them (*oh, shoot, the deadline for the resubmission was yesterday!*): so, my policy is to get rid of what's possible as soon as I can. Second, if among the coauthors there are PhD students or other young scientists, for them it's better to publish sooner than later because there might always be an application around the corner. In any case, I haven't perceived any difference in the reviewer's responses depending on the time of the resubmission, and I've never changed my reviewing's style depending on it.

Comment: And a delay might cause one's paper to miss a publication cycle.

Answer (score 1):

> Based on his experience, the chances of acceptance are therefore higher.

I don’t think that anybody can make robust empirical statements about this.
Journals can’t because revision time also correlates with actual effort put into the revision, and thus they would to have even more reviews to normalise for paper quality. Of course, your colleague knows whether he delayed a resubmission deliberately, but I doubt that he has sufficiently many samples to substantiate a claim¹.

Thus, all that remains are arguments.

<sup>¹ In fact, I have witnessed many scientists exhibit weird superstitions on what will appease reviewers or audiences, presumably based on one or two experiences, where something worked or a reviewer made a bizarre demand. How can I know that these are superstitions? Well, many are clearly contradictory, and they can’t all be right.</sup>

> His rationale is that reviewers might be less inclined to dig in the matter again after a certain time has passed.

From my peer-reviewing experience, I think there are three main flaws with this argument:

- Unless the revision comes very quickly (say, within a week), I have to dig into the topic again anyway, whether it has been three weeks or a year – and I have experienced both.
- I am skeptical that “not digging into the paper” generally leads to more favourable reviews. Suppose my first recommendation on a manuscript has been “major revisions” or worse (otherwise you have little to worry about anyway).
  Then this is the baseline with which I go into the second round of review: The manuscript and response have to convince me that the problems have now been fixed. This can only happen if I engage with the topic and the manuscript. Of course, there are reviewers whose lazy stance is benign, but I see no reason to assume that they predominate or you can predict whether you have such a reviewer.
- If I don’t want to engage with a manuscript again (for whatever reason), there is a decent chance that I simply decline to review. This results in a considerable chance that the editor seeks the opinion of a fresh reviewer, who in turn is much more likely to have completely new issues with your manuscript.

> I doubt this believing that the revised version content is the only decisive factor.

I find that a bit idealistic because peer-reviewers and editors are humans and come with all sorts of biases and similar. But yes, at least my rosy view of my own reviewing is that solving my major concerns is by far the best thing you can do in a revision, be it by amending your manuscript or arguing that my concerns are ill-conceived. There is an amazingly clear-cut difference between resubmissions who try and succeed and those who attempt to wiggle around this. All manuscripts I recommended to reject in a second round spectacularly failed at this hurdle.